# BizTalk only deploy or build and deploy?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am working as a BizTalk integration developer.

Every time I do build and deploy. It's not a problem for a small project, but it's for a huge BizTalk project .

The question is, is it enough to deploy only and no need to build first and then deploy so that the project works correctly and the new changes are applied in the BizTalk Server?

Comment: You probably generally will want to divide BizTalk solutions into quite small projects with only a few artifacts since that is easier to maintain generally speaking for BizTalk. 
For build/deployment I would recommend Deployment Framework for BizTalk even for local development since it comes with a deployment toolbar for use inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You always need to build, before deploying. The only exception might be non-BizTalk or non-.NET files, but only if those files are not retrieved from the `bin` folder but somewhere else during deployment or creation of the deployment package.